# How to get current store ID in async controller

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have an AJAX request POSTing data to a controller in my Magento module.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/page/section/profile?isAjax=true",
    type: "POST",
    data: "profileId=" + profile.id,
    success: function (result) {}
});
```

Starting at http://my-website/store2 I post to the `/profile` endpoint, where I'm trying to access the current store ID in the following (simplified) controller code:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Profile extends Action
{
   /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

   /**
    * Profile constructor
    *
    * @param Context $context
    */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(); // returns 1
        $websiteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website', 0); // returns 0

        return [$storeId, $websiteId];
    }
}
```

however this always returns store ID 1 (default) instead of the expected store ID 2.

I am not currently logged in to Magento admin.

I have tried to obtain this data via e.g. `$this->getRequest()->getParam('website')`, in the controller, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: which data are you trying to get using the getParam function?

Comment: @magefms I have tried to get 'website'. This returns 0.

Comment: can you post your controller code

Comment: check updated answer @strangerpixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I needed to post data to the appropriate store URL, defined in the block beforehand.

Block:

```
public function getEndpointWithStoreCode()
{
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,
        true
        ) . "/page/section/profile?isAjax=true";
}
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "my_module/js/profile" : {
            "profileEndpoint" : "<?= $block->getEndpointWithStoreCode() ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: config.profileEndpoint,
    type: "POST",
    data: "profileId=" + profile.id,
    success: function (result) {}
});
```

By POSTing directly to `/store2/page/section/profile`, the right store scope is locked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in your controller:

```
$this->request()->getParam('website',0);
```

UPDATE:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Profile extends Action
{
   /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

   /**
    * Profile constructor
    *
    * @param Context $context
    */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request= $request;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->request->getParam('website',0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still returns 0 for 'website'.

Comment: did you run the upgrade and other required commands?

Comment: how about changing website to store like `return $this->request->getParam('store',0);` ?

Comment: @strangerpixel I see your code in your post, it return 0 because you are not injecting `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request` in your constructor

Comment: I have tried it locally, it's the same outcome as `$this->getRequest()`, which returns a `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`. To your earlier point, 'store' param is also null. The request object in the controller only gives access to the params I have explicitly posted to it.